# JGroups get main reference of cluster?

Tags: java, cluster-computing, rmi, rpc, jgroups

I want to create a cluster of server replicas with JGroups. I have no problem being able to coordinate communication between the replicas but I do not know how to access, say, the conceptually *main* server within the cluster. The only solution I can think of is the client to connect to the cluster JChannel so it can get the reference to the first member in the group (so if it crashes, the next server replica will be automatically the first and thus the main one) but I believe this creates security issues... Any ideas how I would approach this?

Comment: Never mind, I found my solution.

Comment: Then you should post that as an answer, in case someone runs into the same problem.